# Morita equivalent algebras in a fusion category

Tags: ct.category-theory, fusion-categories, braided-tensor-categories, morita-equivalence

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a braided $\mathbb{k}$-linear fusion category ($\mathbb{k}$ algebraically closed; if necessary to answer my question you can also assume $\mathcal{C}$ to be pivotal or even modular). Two algebras $A,B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ are called *Morita equivalent* if the categories $A\hbox{-}\mathsf{Mod}(\mathcal{C})$ and $B\hbox{-}\mathsf{Mod}(\mathcal{C})$ of (left or right) modules internal to $\mathcal{C}$ are equivalent.

**Questions:**

(1) Is there any alternative, equivalent characterization of Morita equivalence of two algebras which circumvents showing that their module categories are equivalent?

(2) In particular, is there a way to "calculate" the Morita equivalence class of a given algebra?

(3) Is there anything special one can say about the Morita equivalence class of an algebra, e.g. some classification result, maybe by imposing additional properties on the algebra?

Please also refer to literature, thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the answers to these questions for ordinary algebras?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Roughly. For example, $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent if and only if there are bimodules $M$ and $N$ such that $M \otimes_B N \cong A$ and $N \otimes_A M \cong B$ as bimodules. I suppose that this also holds for internal algebras. But are there any other characterizations? Or any literature where such things are summarized?

Comment: You can get much more specific: for ordinary algebras, $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent if and only if $B = e M_n(A) e$ for $e \in M_n(A)$ which is what is called a full idempotent (see the last bit of https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/05/17/generators/ for details).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan OK, thanks. This should generalize immediately to algebras internal to a fusion category. But is there any constructive way to find such a full idempotent for concretely given algebras $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Don't you want the categories of left modules equivalent as right module categories over $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: In this case, the Morita equivalence class of $A$ (under some technical assumptions) can be easily calculated using the internal hom. Namely, Ostrik shows that if $M$ is an $A$-module then $[M,M]$ is Morita equivalent to $A$ and every algebra Morita equivalent to $A$ arises this way.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139

Comment: @MarcelBischoff Thanks, this is helpful - I didn't think about that! What happens if the algebras are not semisimple indecomposable? Is there any similar result?

Comment: If you are considering fusion categories you probably only want to consider Algebras whose bimodule categories are fusion again. Why restrict to fusion categories otherwise?

Comment: You might find [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2631) of Pinhas and mine interesting.

Answer (score 1):

in the algebra case, B=eMn(A)e "because" B=End_A (P) with P f.g. proyective, so, finding e is the same as give a presentation of P as a direct summand of A^n. Also, P=F(B) where F is the functor giving the equivalence between B-mod and A-mod, that is f.g. projective because B is so as B-module.
In summary, "e" is so explicit as the functor..

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? If I understand correctly, explicitly finding $P$ and hence the full idempotent $e$ amounts to finding the equivalence $F$ between the module categories, but this is exactly what I wanted to circumvent.

Comment: well, I can say "e" is so explicit as the module  F(B)", (instead of "as F"), and maybe you can say something in a particular case, just because B is a particular B-module and so F(B). For instance, in the algebra case, if A is such that every f.g. projective is free, then every Morita equivalent ring to A is necesarily of the form Mn(A).